# BigQuery SQL: Conditionally Count Column Values (if only one code exists from list) While Grouping By Unique ID

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, count, conditional-statements

Let's say I have the following sample input table:

| ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 323F |
| 1234 | 327F |
| 1234 | 328F |
| 1234 | 333F |
| 2234 | 327F |
| 2234 | 342F |
| 3314 | 327F |
| 3314 | 357F |

I want to create a new column called "Count".  The "Count" column gets a 1 value if and only if across the entire table the unique ID **has only one** of the following codes (in the "Code" column) in the list below:

- 323F, 327F, 328F, 333F, 357F

Otherwise the ID gets a "Count" value of 0.

Given the rules above, my desired output table is below:

| ID | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 0 |
| 2234 | 1 |
| 3314 | 0 |

How do I do this using BigQuery SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select ID, 
  (
    select if(count(*) = 1, 1, 0)
    from unnest(Codes) as code
    join unnest(['323F', '327F', '328F', '333F', '357F']) as code
    using(code)
  ) as `count`
from (
  select ID, array_agg(distinct Code) Codes
  from your_table
  group by ID
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question, output is

[image]

Comment: thank you!  What is this line of code doing conceptually?  select if(count(*) = 1, 1, 0)

Comment: if it reflect "has only one" requirement - if count of matches not 1 the output is 0, otherwise is 1

Comment: There is a shorter solution:  `SELECT ID, IF(COUNT(DISTINCT IF( Code IN ('323F', '327F', '328F', '333F', '357F'), code, NULL))=1,1,0) from your_table group by 1`